# Finding the iteration/counter for built in search in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that performs binary and sequential and plots the iteration of each search. however I'm trying to use a built in java Search `Collections.binarySearch(list,index)` the return value is the index/location of the value that I'm searching. Is it possible that I can make the return value to be the counter/iteration ?

```
for(int i =0; i < 30; i++){
     //java built in search
    Integer retVal3 = Collections.binarySearch(list,n[i]);
    val3.add(retVal3);
}
```

Comment: just copy that method implementation and modify as you need

Comment: Well, you could provide your own custom compator that just uses `Comparable` and counts the number of comparisons performed. If you have a look at the source code you'll see that `c.compare(midVal, key)` called exactly once per iteration.

Comment: If I understood right, you need to increase a counter every time an element is found.
First of all, you need to have your list sorted before the loop, to avoid additional n^2*log(n) additional complexity. After that you just could do the following: 'counter = retVal >=0 ? counter + 1 : counter;'

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 options:

1. Roll your own binary search method and add your counting/logging there.
2. Use a custom comparator that counts the compare operations.

Option 1 could be done by just copying the source of `Collections.binarySearch()`.

Option 2 could use a comparator like this:

```
class CountingComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
  private final Comparator<T> delegate;
  private int counter;

  public CountingComparator( Comparator<T> delegate ) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare( T left, T right ) {
    counter++;
    return delegate.compare( left, right );
  }    

  public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
  }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
//since you're searching integers the actual comparator will use the natural order of the elements
CountingComparator<Integer> comp = new CountingComparator<Integer>(Comparator.naturalOrder());    
int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, key, comp);    
int iterationCount = comp.getCounter();
```

Note that you'd need a new instance of that comparator for *each* call to `binarySearch()`.